# Source code not fully executing. (JS)

Tags: javascript

Honestly, I'm not sure what the real problem is, how-ever it's only calling the update function once... I'm used to multi threading and I've hardly done any programming with JS. So if anyone can help me, I would be very grateful. I believe it has to do with the setTimeout function however I'm not sure..
Here is my source:

```
<html>  
<p id='date_label'>0</p>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var dateObject=new Date();
function update(){
    var time=dateObject.getHours()+" : "+dateObject.getMinutes()+" : "+dateObject.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById('date_label').innerHTML=time;
    setTimeout(main,100);
};
function main(){
    update();
};
main();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's calling it many times, it's just using the same object defined at the start. Change it so `dateObject` is redefined on each call:

```
function update(){
    var dateObject=new Date();
    var time=dateObject.getHours()+" : "+dateObject.getMinutes()+" : "+dateObject.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById('date_label').innerHTML=time;
    setTimeout(main,100);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, like I said, I'm very new to JS.